# Javascript - keep reference to function before changing it

Tags: javascript, function, reference

My code looks like this:

```
function x(a,b)
{
     return a + b;
}

var f = x;

function x(a,b)
{
     return a - b;
}

var res = f(2,1);
```

I expect that the result is 3 as f is pointing to function x before modifying it, but it isn't the case, how can I keep a reference to a function that is foing to be redefined?

Answer (score 4):

Function declarations are processed before expressions. Therefore, from the point of view of the interpreter, your code is interpreted as this:

```
function x(a,b)
{
     return a + b;
}

function x(a,b)
{
     return a - b;
}

var f = x;

var res = f(2,1);
```

The solution is to re-assign the function using a function expression instead of a function declaration. This is because as I mentioned above expressions are processed after declarations:

```
function x(a,b)
{
     return a + b;
}

var f = x;

x = function (a,b) // <--------- this fixes your problem
{
     return a - b;
}

var res = f(2,1);
```

Note, that since declarations are processed before expressions, the following would work as well:

```
var f = x;

x = function (a,b)
{
     return a - b;
}

var res = f(2,1);

function x(a,b) // this is processed first
{
     return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Functions and variable declarations (but not variable assignments) are "hoisted" to the top of their containing scope.

So your code is equivalent to this:

```
function x(a,b) {
  return a + b;
}

function x(a,b) {  //this overwrites the previous function declaration
  return a - b;
}

var f;
var res;

f = x;

res = f(2,1);  //1
```

It should now be clear why `f(2,1)` is 1 instead of 2.

You can overcome this by creating functions as variables instead:

```js
var x = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

var f = x;
console.log(f(2, 1));  //3

var x = function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

var f = x;
console.log(f(2, 1));  //1
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign your functions to variables when creating them:

```js
var f1 = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

var f2 = f1;

f1 = function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

alert( f1(2,1) );  // < Will subtract
alert( f2(2,1) );  // < Will add
```

This allows you to easily clone the function.